# Google Recaptcha V2 Invisible - massive increase in load time - ruins page speed optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

**Problem Summary:**

Google V2 ReCapcha kills all the page speed tuning work that was done just to load in the little "invisible" [not really invisible] iFrames

**Situation:**

Got a great SEM landing page, well built, gzipped, minified JS/css, CDN, minimal fonts lightning fast 99% A page speed score...

**But once the JS layer is activated**

Google V2 Invisible ReCapcha attempts to handle 3 FORM elements on the page (lead form, newsletter, and Twilio based SMS 'click to call' form) speed score suffers (and not by an acceptable amount, by a lot)

Image says it all:
[image]

Been a problem for years now, always known about it, but figured maybe there was a solution by now?

All forms are 100% AJAX. Fine with using something else, maybe V3? async defer, tried with deferred and not deferred - load time to deliver the JS files from Google alone *seems* 'unreasonable'... (tried grabbing the JS files and serving them locally, unorthodox and 'not work' anyway)

**Open to suggestions.**

Comment: weird - all the invisible recaptcha demos load that file in 17-20ms

Comment: still a problem to this day. just speed tuned a WP site for a client, the theme author decided to load the ReCapcha library on EVERY page (instead of just where needed on the 1 page with a contact form). rooted that problem out: page speed went from 69% to a 91%... lol. But I digress: main problem is ReCapcha is killing us on speed. Consider a site that wants an email signup form on EVERY page... Try testing it out when there are multiple forms on 1 landing page: Lead gen form, newsletter, and Twilio based SMS 'click to call' form